# Run javascript on headless browser with specific website as origin

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, browser, headless, javascript

I'm using ubuntu server (only terminal) and I have a javascript that must be run from a specific website (to avoid cross-domain issues).

Basicly I would follow this steps if I were in a convencional browser:

1. Open browser
2. Open a website
3. Open console and run javascript code

So, how could I do this in terminal?

Comment: `chrome headless + puppeter` or `casperjs`

Comment: Wouldn't Selenium work as well?

Comment: Yes, but it's bloat ware

Comment: There's also firefox's marionette

Comment: Do I need to change my code to work with puppeter? Or there is a way to just open and run it from puppeter?

Comment: Code ? Where is your code, you just described a task list ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample realCode™, using the fresh and maintained [chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/chrome-headless) via [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) and [puppeteer](/questions/tagged/puppeteer) module :

```
// https://codeburst.io/a-guide-to-automating-scraping-the-web-with-javascript-chrome-puppeteer-node-js-b18efb9e9921

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://99bitcoins.com/bitcoin-rich-list-top100/#addresses');
    await page.waitFor(3000);

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        var obj = {};
        var data = document.querySelectorAll('table.t99btc-rich-list tr');
        for (var i = 1; i<=100; i++) {
           obj[i] = {
               "hash": data[i].querySelector('td > a').innerText,
               "balance": data[i].querySelector('td:nth-of-type(3)').innerText
           }
        }

        return obj;

    });

    browser.close();
    return result;
};

scrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(value, null, 4));
});
```

### Usage :

```
node top_xbt.js
```

Comment: I accepted it since I followed your suggestion of using puppeteer

Comment: It's the more modern tool and that avoid casperjs specific corner cases